# Can iTunes gift cards be used to make in-app purchases?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, apple-id, itunes-store, in-app-purchase

Does Apple allow the use of iTunes gift cards (in this case a Japanese iTunes gift card with a Japanese Apple ID) to buy an in-app purchase (for in-game currency)?

Comment: 'Legal' or allowed by Apple?

Comment: This site can't answer that.  Laws are different in each area.

Comment: @fsb never mind, allowed by Apple

Answer (score 1):

Why would it *not* be allowed by Apple?

If it's a Japanese iTunes gift card for an Apple ID with the Japanese iTunes Store, then that's what the gift card is for. You can use it to purchase Apple software, 3rd party apps, music, etc so long as they're from Apple's Japanese stores (i.e. iTunes Store, App Store, Apple Music, iCloud, etc). In-app purchases are included as well.

What you would **not** be able to do is use it to add credit to an Apple ID based in another country or connected to another store. For example, if you had another Apple ID for the US iTunes Store, then you wouldn't be able to redeem a Japanese iTunes gift card for that Apple ID.

Comment: What if I don’t have a real japanese address?

Comment: The address is irrelevant because you've already got the Apple ID registered. In other words, once you've already got the Apple ID set up with Apple, and once you have credit on it, you can use that any way you like. More specifically, you've got a Japanese Apple ID set up, so any credit you have on that can be spent on Apple's Japanese stores as you wish. Purchases do not run some sort of check against your address.

Comment: Where you *may* run into difficulty is if you try to attach a credit card to the account that didn't originate in Japan, as the authentication process may pick that up. In that case you would need to use iTunes Gift Cards for the Japanese market, or get your hands on a Japanese credit card.